# Git, tell me when a remote branch that I am tracking is removed

Tags: git, git-branch

Is there a good way to see when or all local branches which has been setup to track a remote branch where the remote branch has been removed?

example.

I track the remote branch `hotfix` and it is removed on remote (usually due to being merged into `dev`). I would like to see this somehow so that I can take action (normally being to remove my local branch).

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try, after a `git fetch`:

```
git remote prune --dry-run
```

to check if there is any stale tracking branch:

> prune
>
> Deletes all stale tracking branches under `<name>`.
>   These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "`remotes/<name>`".
>
> With `--dry-run` option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

Comment: Did not know about prune but that is an awesome command! Thanks